# VS Code User, C++, CMake, BUild and Release, SDK

Tags: c++, cmake, build, sdk, release

while build SDK in Visual Studio Code using CMAke i am getting this error I tried all the available solution on Internet but not yet resolve please help?[[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXiU6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oraO.png)

ERROR MESSAGE

-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
Generator

```
NMake Makefiles
```

does not support platform specification, but platform

```
x64
```

was specified.

CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Sony_SDK/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
i want the solution of this error

Comment: provide the cmake command you ran as _text_ and not as an image of text (see [ask]). And as instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a platform is only possible on the Visual Studio generator.
Either use the Visual Studio generator (`-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"`) or drop the platform argument.
Or consult the documentation of the SDK you received.